# How should the [history] tag be disambiguated?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There is a [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) which currently has many meanings for which other tags exist:

- [browser-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-history) for managing browser history in web applications and web browser extensions
- [history.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history.js) for the JavaScript API to the HTML5 History APIs
- [html5-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-history) for the HTML5 History API
- [input-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-history) for saving and recalling previous inputs in an entry box
- [revision-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revision-history) for version control

There may well be other meanings that I've missed.

Should we reserve the tag [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) for the history of programming concepts, which has no alternate tag? (This is what we do on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com): we have [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/history/info) for the history of Unix, and [command-history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/command-history/info) for command history in shells.) Or should we leave it ambiguous? What should we do with the history tag?

---

After a dearth of responses, I edited the tag wiki to declare [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) to be about the history of programming concepts, listing other tags for browser histories, input histories, etc. I assume this is consensual since nobody's objected after two years, but [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) still needs a massive cleanup — or manual disambiguation.

<sub>N.B. I wrote the tag wiki to remove the request for burnination, which had never been discussed on Meta.</sub>

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343030/this-tag-is-history

Comment: Note that since this question was posted, [history questions have been declared off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow), so the tag name is no longer relevant for this meaning.

Answer (score 8):

As long as just plain [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) exists lazy askers will stop when they get to it instead of finding the correct detailed tag (the existence of a clear tag-wiki excerpt notwithstanding).

Perhaps ban [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) and add [history-of-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history-of-programming) to the proposed list.

Comment: History of Programming is off-topic on Stack Overflow.  Programmers.SE *might* entertain such questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I just saw your comment here, which [has been taken as authoritative](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6813129/8). Why is history of programming off-topic on SO? Can you please point out to a meta discussion that rules this topic? The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) states that a “practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development” is on-topic — if you want to make the case that history questions are not practical or not answerable, please do so — in an answer.

Comment: @Gilles: If you're trying to evaluate whether or not a question is on-topic at Stack Overflow by looking at the bullets in the Help Center, you should know that we regard those bullets as a cartesian intersection, not a cartesian union.  In other words, on-topic questions have to fulfill *all* of the conditions in those bullets, not just one.  Otherwise, people would be cherry-picking topicality using that sole bullet as justification for asking their far-afield questions.