# Are questions about programming history in scope for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I can only guess, of course, but I'm guessing that this question was downvoted because it doesn't seem to be asking a programming question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26448825/when-the-idea-of-pairing-two-lists-and-the-name-zip-were-zipped-together

(There's no other obvious reason to me why it would be downvoted: it's not obviously unresearched, quite well presented, etc.).

At first I thought "Oh, this belongs at Programmers, let me flag it for migration", but then I thought "hang about, there's this [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag specifically for this kind of question!"

So is this question in scope or not?

Comment: "There's no other obvious reason to me why it would be downvoted..." I'm continually puzzled by the idea of questioning votes. There needs to be no obvious reason other than a user has the required tools and time to do so. On both sides, up and down, votes are levied for reasons not stated as proper on the site; just [look around](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851672/hash-funcion-in-c/26851736#comment42266047_26851736); I see it every day.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils A downvote is a message. It says "I think this post is not useful or unclear.  In our ongoing striving to make things better it strikes me as perfectly natural to want to understand what makes it that way, so the question itself, and later ones, can be improved. The question isn't questioning the act (IE I don't think you should have downvoted) it is questioning the rationale (IE what is it that is unclear nor not useful about this question).  In this instance, it raises a general question about what's actually in scope.   That seems to me to be a worthwhile question to ask...

Comment: Side note: I've asked related questions a while ago on questions about historical details of language - [Are "why particular language feature was designed this way" on-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved), with answer "yes as one can often find solid reason".

Comment: Yes, that message is conveyed by some, namely those who honor the voting system and vote for those reasons. And I don't believe there's anything wrong with asking your question. I also didn't view it as you opining on the votes. I was only pointing out that it seems some believe there's a force stopping people from arbitrarily voting; there's not. Questions can be received differently based on the time of day you post it. IOW, I'm not sure how well reason can be applied to the voting system.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - Ah, I understand: true.  It's like a noisy signal... we extract what information from it we can and do our best :)

Comment: I just came here from the tag recommendation `history` - how (if at all) should I tag a question about language features nowadays removed from the language, e.g. if I find one in legacy code and need help to port it? Similarly for tool features, parameters, etc.? I feel that a question "why does <xy> not work" is not meaningfully more or less valid, just because the answer is "it used to work in <tool version z> but not anymore". Especially as we should probably expect that answer to be unknown to the one asking.

Answer (score 31):

It is on topic on Software Engineering.SE, see [What topics are not “part of the SDLC” but are nevertheless still on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8215/31260)

> History questions are still on-topic, provided the OP can demonstrate some relevance with an ongoing concern related to the SDLC...

There's even one of them promoted on [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/11/why-was-the-first-compiler-written-before-the-first-interpreter/).

Note that questions that tend to be of the 'go hunt down this bit of trivia' (for varying definitions of trivia) may be less well received (a "How have languages influenced CPU design" was recently closed as too broad and "Who first used the phrase “Those who only live by the GUI, will die by the GUI”" was fairly promptly closed after being asked). It can be rather hit and miss for how the community responds to the question.

Note that even if it isn't off-topic, the question may get down voted for lack of research (part of the text in the mouseover guidance for down vote).

[History tag](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history?sort=active) on Software Engineering.SE has had a bit of history to it too with going back and forth on the 'on or off topic' debate. The best (and most recent) summary of what is expected from a history question can be found at: [Is programming history on topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5634/40980) in which the guidelines given are:

- Askers *must* do their homework
- Askers *must* share their research
- Questions *must* be answerable
- Programming history questions should be about *programming* history
- No trivia

A question that fails to meet these points is more likely to get closed and down voted <del>and an angry horde of Software Engineering.SE users will ping your mods and invade MSO</del>.

---

To the specific question mentioned, the OP might want to make sure that they have done a bit of research first and present that along with the question. Just tossing out idle curiosity and shower thoughts may not make for good questions.

> The idea of pairing the elements of two (or more) lists to operate on them must be older than the invention of Lisp's `mapcar`
>
> ...

They should be sure that they are at least familiar with the [languages that predate Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_programming_languages#First_programming_languages) and consider if it was something new within Lisp that one is seeing. This should be fairly easy as you are dealing with (as listed in Wikipedia) six major languages, one of which [was listed as a forerunner of Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_Processing_Language).

One may get better answers if they describe what they understand how Lisp is influenced by IPL and where its other influences came from.

The answer to the question is probably somewhere in the [Information Processing Language Manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/rand/ipl/Information_Processing_Language-V_Second_Edition_1964.pdf) - if you can find a zip function (or one that can be easily created from other functions), that's where Lisp got it. If you can't, Lisp didn't likely get it from Fortran or Cobol.

---

The mentioned question would likely be a less than ideal migration given the 'homework' point of the history test:

> If the answer to a history question can be found on a freely available reference site (read: Wikipedia) or the language's / system's / project's freely available documentation, then the question is **off topic** and will be closed as such.

As I mentioned, the answer is probably in the documentation for one of the languages - it's the [higher order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)#Language_comparison) for mapping two lists.

Comment: (just a brief comment to note that it's not my question, I just stumbled across it)

Comment: Hm, that Wikipedia page does not answer the question "when was the term *zip* coined" - it only suggests Haskell and Erlang as possible candidate languages.

Comment: @Bergi my point was more one of "the question doesn't even show that this much was read and investigated".  The asker *must* do their homework *first*.  The more homework done, the better the question.  A question that has done no digging into the nature of the term is much like a question with "why does this code work {dump of code}" in Stack Overflow. In both cases the question should take the reader as far as it can and then ask for help in the next step ("I got to erlang, and then got lost") rather than asking the person answering the question to do all the work.

Comment: History questions have been contentious since the earliest days of P.SE.  I remember an early question that was closed as "Too objective".

Answer (score 22):

No, it's not; questions on Stack Overflow are on-topic if they're specific questions about a programming problem (or misunderstanding), or similarly about tools used for programming.

Questions about the history of programming, or its concepts, are absolutely not on-topic because they can't solve a programming problem, unless it's an odd way of working out which version of language X needs to be used to incorporate a concept, in which case it *might* fit. But I'd still vote to close on the grounds of language documentation *probably* answering the question (but I'm not entirely sure of that).

Comment: Does this mean that the `history` tag should be removed?

Comment: @GreenAsJade looking at the tag and the questions in it, it could likely use a great cleaning.

Comment: @MichaelT, There may be two types of history questions. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A463304+[history] Either questions about history, or questions related to a feature called history.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey correct... And the tag wiki says they are about the concept of history (like the question in question) rather than the implementation of history and undo.

Comment: Note however that language design rationale questions are practical -- knowing the purpose of a feature will influence how you use it.  The question this meta post concerns is definitely not an practical history question, though.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey. And disambiguating that is what tag wikis are for. [Removed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14466159/revisions).

Answer (score 6):

It is pretty much settled<sup>1</sup> that History questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and that they are *often* (but not always) on-topic on Software Engineering (see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276368/139985)).

Another place where questions about the history of computing are on topic is the [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) site.  According to the site's [What topics can I ask about here?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page:

> Retrocomputing involves the restoration, preservation, history and
> maintenance of computer and gaming systems of yesteryear.
>
> Questions are most welcomed on:
>
> - ...
> - Computing history and persons with a historic relation to computing.  [[history]](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history),

However, they do mention that "what if" or "alternative history" questions are off-topic, as they are speculative not objective.

---

<sup>1 - I present the voting for the *other* answers to this question as my supporting evidence for this.  However, this is not the real point of my answer, so don't get hung up on it ... if you disagree.</sup>

Comment: "It is pretty much settled that History questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow" I seem to have missed the memo. Can you please link to where this has been settled?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - See the other answers to this question.  But that's not what my answer is *really* about.

Answer (score 3):

Since this question was recently active again, I'll add my two cents.

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

It's unclear what the practical significance of the linked question is; it seems to be motivated by a desire to satisfy the OP's idle curiosity, which may be entertaining but isn't a good, on-topic question.

Questions should be tied to some specific problem that the OP is actively working on. If they have some programming question that this helps to answer, it's on-topic.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds anything to the already clear outcome from other answers, other than describing interest in programming history as "idle curiosity" - an unnecessary slur.

Answer (score -5):

I'm not sure how to generalize from this but one data point: I had a successful history question.

[What did John McCarthy mean by *pornographic programming*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547142/what-did-john-mccarthy-mean-by-pornographic-programming)

Comment: In modern days, a question like this would *probably* be a better fit on [Programmers.SE]. It is a whiteboard- or conceptual-style question, rather than a practical programming question. A perfectly valid, useful question, mind you, but I'm not totally sure it would be best asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Understood. It scrapes by on the homework criterion. Opening a bounty helped too, but it has to be open to do that.

Comment: Please do not continue discussing how and when the question was closed in this comment section. If anyone wants to point out an issue, please post a separate Meta question, as usual.

Comment: @blackgreen If a meta question was posted, it'll be downvoted out of the front page within a hour, by the organized voting ring, before it ever reaches the intended  general audience.

Comment: @TheMaster for that matter, you definitely have even less reach by debating in this comment thread.

Answer (score -14):

Programming history is on-topic for Stack Overflow according to the help center:

> if your question generally covers ...
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Questions about programming history *are* questions about software tools, at least if they're asking about the history of programming languages, frameworks, and other such software tools. Furthermore, history is closely tied to language design, and there is often a practical answer to *why* a software tool was designed in a certain way.

For example, one may ask [Where does 'Hello world' come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/602237/5740428). This is an interesting question about a commonly taught example in software development.

- It is obviously **answerable** because the origins of "Hello world" can be traced back to some learning resources.
- It is arguably **practical** because the example is used so much, and is therefore of great interest to the programming community. Knowing the history of the materials you teach or reference *is* a practical problem.

Personally, I think [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) should be renamed to/merged with [programming-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-history) so that it no longer gets mistaken so much for questions about browser history, etc. There is a problem with the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history)tag, but the problem isn't that history/design/rationale questions are off-topic.

Comment: Something "being used so much" and (according to this answer) "therefore of great interest" does not mean knowing its origin is a "practical problem" in any way. I don't follow that logic.

Comment: Being aware of the history, design, or rationale of the tools you use or teach is a practical problem. It can help you be aware of how those tools should be used if you know the historical context. If you teach programming, it might help you satisfy a student's curiosity. Note that there are many [language-lawyer] questions that aren't really practical problems, but rather asked out of academic interest or pure curiosity, and I don't see people arguing that those are off-topic for the website. In any case, the help center doesn't reflect that these questions are off-topic.

Comment: You are twisting the definition. No, "being aware of the history, design and rationale" is not a practical problem at all.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, and we'll simply have to disagree here. The problem is that it's too subjective what constitutes a "practical" problem, and the help center doesn't list history/design/rationale questions as explicitly off-topic for the website. In any case, there needs to be something explicit in the help center, and/or a close reason for questions that are about such topics. Having a handful of people come together on Meta and override site policy through their personal opinion and personal interpretation of site policy in this way isn't great.

Comment: One could argue you are doing exactly that, trying to get a handful of other users together on meta to override site-policy, by trying to describe as "practical problems" something that eminently it's not. But using that kind of language, as you are doing, is simply not helpful.

Comment: I'm not overriding site policy by just stating what my interpretation of site policy is. I would be overriding site policy if I ignored what the help center says, ignored the lack of a proper close reason, and used a meta post as a justification for outlawing a topic, without prior agreement from mods and staff, and without prior updates to close reasons and the help center documentation.

Comment: Other users are simply acting on their interpretation of the site policy, as this is supposed to work. Meta discussions serve to clarify our collective interpretation of the site policy, and are routinely used as pointers for other users to read about these discussions. You seem to be referring to things happening that are not immediately clear from reading this post, in any case. The arguments posted in this post for defending "history" questions seem very weak to me. Bye.

Comment: Taking action such as closing or deleting questions for being off-topic is a pretty drastic action and needs to be backed up by more than a handful of upvotes. It influences what should be done about tens of thousands of existing and future questions. As things stand, the help center doesn't unambiguously state that such history/design/rationale questions are off topic, there are many thousands of [history], [language-design], etc. questions which may not be "practical", there isn't a proper close reason in the UI, etc. Those issues should be addressed prior to "DO NOT USE" or burnination.

Comment: You seem to think actions you disagree with are "pretty drastic actions", when they are simply users using the site tools as they see fit. Votes are for that.  Since neither this question nor answer mentions burnination or tag wiki edits, that last comment is lost on me. And now really, I'm gone. Bye, peace.

Comment: This Q&A is being cited as the "best piece of evidence" for why questions about programming history are off-topic. That's what peaked my interest in it. The opinion that such questions are off-topic is relatively popular, but I don't believe that it's sufficient to influence site policy in such a drastic way, especially considering that it's very inconsistent with other "non-practical" topics like [language-design].

Comment: "and there is often a practical answer to why a software tool was designed in a certain way." - That does not imply that the question covers a practical problem. "It is arguably practical because the example is used so much, and is therefore of great interest to the programming community. Knowing the history of the materials you teach or reference is a practical problem." Suppose you didn't know the history. How would that lack of knowledge inhibit you from teaching their use?

Comment: It's only on-topic if the OP identifies a practical problem that the information helps them understand; otherwise, it's just random trivia.