# Would a question about user agent strings be on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

In [trying to find a proper place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243359/274106) for [a question about the current format of browser user agent strings as relating to their history](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/why-do-we-still-use-mozilla-5-0-in-user-agent-strings), and [was directed to SO, if doubtedly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243359/where-would-a-question-about-user-agent-strings-be-on-topic#comment795382_243359). **Would this SE be the right one to ask my question?**

I'm especially concerned since I got a message saying:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.

and, of course, would not want this to happen.

Comment: I don't think it's about that question's actual content, but about your overall recorded behavior on SO (possibly asking poor questions in the past) actually.

Comment: I don't know much about user agent Strings, so I can't answer your direct question, but often it's more *how* you ask. Be sure to read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. Also, try to improve your previous down-voted questions to avoid getting blocked.

Comment: BTW, I don't know if there *is* an SE site that would be on-topic for. You *might* have luck on Programmers.SE, but I would be cautious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that question would not be on-topic; as it is not about programming.

Note that the linked question that "proves" such a question belongs here: [Why do all browsers' user agents start with "Mozilla/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-mozilla-string-is-present-on-all-browsers-user-agent) is from 2009, when the rules were a lot different.

Also related: [Are questions about programming history in scope for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow)

The question-ban warning has nothing to do with this post; but is related to your past asking history.

Comment: Alright. I know about the question-ban warning, but might've not made that clear. Thank you, anyway!