# Improve help center documentation for what questions are "practical"

Tags: discussion, help-center

The help center article [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) currently explains that any question has to be:

> a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

in order to be on-topic for the website. "Answerable" is relatively clear, but "practical" is quite subjective. The [Oxford dictionary provides multiple definitions](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/practical):

> **practical** *adjective*
>
> ###### connected with real things
>
> 1 connected with real situations rather than with ideas or theories
>
> - to have gained **practical** experience of the work
> - [...]
>
> ###### useful
>
> 3 (of things) useful or suitable
>
> - a **practical** little car, ideal for the city
> - [...]

It is unclear whether *practical* in the help center refers to *useful* problems, or "real" (non-theoretical) problems.

Let's look at a few topics:

- **Programming history** ([history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history)) is considered to be off-topic by most users on Meta, see [Are questions about programming history in scope for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276366/).
- **Language design** ([language-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design)) has not seen similar controversy, even though many questions are equally not practical. If it's off-topic to ask about the history of a language, why would it be on-topic to ask about the rationale of a language?
- **Computer science and mathematics** ([math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math), [computer-science](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/computer-science), [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm), ...) are sometimes considered on-topic for the website, although https://cs.stackexchange.com/ and https://math.stackexchange.com/ are frequently cited as better communities to ask such questions. It is unclear to what extent these academic topics are on-topic for Stack Overflow. They are often not about a "practical problem", but they are useful, and they are often related to a software system in *some* way.
- **Language lawyering** ([language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer)) is often not about solving any specific, practical issue. For example, the question [C++11 introduced a standardized memory model. What does it mean? And how is it going to affect C++ programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6319146/5740428) is asking about the C++11 memory model, which is a highly theoretical question. However, I yet have to see a single language-lawyering question receive a historical lock for being "too theoretical", or any effort to burninate [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer).

In summary, the use of "practical" in the help center isn't entirely clear. It could also be perceived as arbitrary why highly theoretical questions about computer science or language technicalities are on-topic, but questions about language history aren't. It can also be perceived as arbitrary why questions about language design, rationale, etc. are not off-topic, but questions about history are.

**The help center should use clearer language, and if these topics are off-topic for Stack Overflow, the help center could state so explicitly.** I'm interested in whether you think these topics are "practical", and how the help center could make this clear.

Comment: There can be practical programming question about those other topics. Not so much about "history".

Comment: @yivi by what standard is a language rationale question "practical", but a language history question isn't? [Why do stacks typically grow downwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2035568/5740428) is asking about a historical convention, and that is arguably more practical than a large quantity of language design questions.

Comment: "It is unclear whether practical in the help center refers to useful problems, or "real" (non-theoretical) problems." Why does it have to be either or? Both of these seem useful for real.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it doesn't have to be either or. However, if a question being "practical" (as in useful) is enough to be on-topic for the website, then questions about programming history which are useful are also on-topic for SO. The community largely disagrees with this though. Therefore it's problematic that the documentation in the help center doesn't make this clear, and that's what this Q&A aims to solve.

Comment: @JanSchultke I’m not sure that’s what the meta Q&A says. Rather I see it as conforming that history *alone* is not sufficient. The specific question this was about (paraphrased "when was the name zip first used like that?") absolutely does not seem useful, so generalising the specific consensus seems to stretch things quite a bit.

Comment: This is my general interpretation of the help center, it leaves way too much up to whatever is most convenient to a person that day. When it comes to the definition of practical my interpretation is that both are implied; it needs to be tied to something "real" (like a real problem, a real error, real code, a real algorithm) and it needs to be useful, since until the company finally fesses up that they don't care about usefulness anymore and only care about traffic, that is still one of the primary quality gauges we use for voting.

Comment: I guess the "problem" is always with the very old questions, back when the community didn't even know what they wanted with SO, and those questions and tags then get ignored when the time passed...

Comment: @AndrewT. well then the problem is also with new questions, since people really don't know what they want with SO today either :)

Comment: *..."Answerable" is relatively clear, but "practical" is quite subjective....* It's all subjective, they're guidelines rather than an exhaustive list.

Comment: The site documentation is atrocious, including re what is an appropriate question. But I can't support the viewpoints in the bullets.

Comment: Re *"questions about language design"*: The existence of the new site [Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/tour) (PLDI) might or might not suggest a large fractions of them are off-topic on Stack Overflow and/or not well received. Or just a way to escape [Eternal September](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/)?

Comment: "Why do stacks typically grow downwards? is asking about a historical convention, and that is arguably more practical than a large quantity of language design questions." I can't even begin to imagine the reasoning for that argument. Knowing about a "historical convention" does not help you write idiomatic code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the direction in which a stack grows is quite important in the domain of systems programming. The convention of growing negatively in terms of address space is surprising at first, and knowing the historical reasons behind it can greatly improve your understanding of this behavior. In general, learning the "why" behind something is an essential part of a learning experience. I would argue that if you don't understand how or why the stack grows in what direction, you may struggle with writing assembly, for example.

Comment: Sure. However, knowing *that* it grows in a particular direction and knowing *why* are separate and barely related questions, *especially* if your characterization of the "why" answer is "historical convention".

Comment: The difference between true understanding and brute memorization is not just memorizing how things work, but understanding why they work a certain way. Your claim was that the former doesn't help you write idiomatic code, and I believe that true understanding is often necessary to accomplish that. Many people also find memorization difficult if they don't understand historical background or rationale.

Answer (score 14):

The more strictly you define "practical", the easier you make it to find loopholes.

If you turn the mention of "practical" into a more specific list of subjects / classifications, then you imply that anything and everything that's *not* on the list, doesn't fall under that rule.

Comment: "this includes, but is not limited to: <....>". examples are a good thing. they can add clarity and concreteness. for example, such example giving is used in the meta post on generative-AI being temporarily banned, and in the previous revision of the CoC.

Comment: @starball I agree that'd be better, but OP seems to be arguing that any room for interpretation is too much. I don't think "no room for interpretation" is possible.

Answer (score 7):

The guidelines in the help center aren't directly outlining what is and isn't off topic, they're outlining the kinds of questions that are likely to be received well here. We have no close reason that fits "This question isn't practical." Rather, most questions that are impractical often are poorly received.

There's no real value in saying theoretical questions are off topic, because they aren't, and saying they are on topic doesn't express what the existing statement is trying to express.

Comment: What you're saying basically sounds like "let's let the voting system do its thing". Impractical questions could simply be downvoted, if they were poorly received. I see value in clearer guidance because people are closing and deleting questions for being off-topic based on their subjective standards. This is arguably weaponizing the moderation tools users are given, and may be an abuse of power unless it is clear that the Stack Overflow website does not accept such content. Basically, if people use moderation tools to enforce off-topicness, I think we need clear guidance to resolve disputes.

Comment: That's exactly what i'm saying. We have close reasons for very specific categories of questions, everything else is to be handled with voting.

Comment: When you say voting, does that include down/upvoting, or voting to close and delete as well?

Comment: Just up and down, clearly, given the alternative was not that.

Comment: Then I think we agree actually. I also think that anything subjective can be handled through down/upvotes. Clear violations of site policy should be handled through close/delete votes, but then site policy needs to be clear. For example, users voted to close and delete [When were the idea of pairing two lists and the name "zip" zipped together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26448825/5740428) for being a question about history, and they consider this to be off-topic. If people are taking such measures, it needs to be clear whether this use of moderation tools is appropriate.

Comment: We have a close reason for subjective questions, so that doesn't fall into the same bucket.

Comment: We do have a close reason "*Not about programming or software development*
Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. […]" which covers three out of the four bullet points in the list of the help centre article. While this doesnt cover the one bullet under discussion here, it suggests the article does define what isn’t on topic.

Comment: Yes, however, that isn't the purpose of the article, the purpose is to help the user craft a question that will be well received. Obviously, it'd need to be on topic *too* to be well received. My point is we can't just take the article and use it to justify abusing existing close reasons for reasons they aren't designed for.