# Edit war for two questions with the [c++-faq] tag

Tags: discussion, edits, edit-wars

#### The pre-history

To give you the history leading up to this, I have recently asked about what the proper usage of the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag is: [What should we do about the [c++-faq] tag and its questionable uses?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426668/5740428)

This question is essentially asking the community to discuss what the proper usage of the tag is. It got a fair amount of attention and votes, but overall wasn't well-received, and no one answered it. The most upvoted comments on it are:

> It (the downvotes) could also be that some people question the utility of the [c++-faq] tag at all

and

> Some of the down-votes could be coming from thoughts of, "are we really rehashing all of this yet again?" Please. Enough.

In other words, it looks like the community doesn't want the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag at all, or strongly doesn't care to discuss it. Of course, the responses could be interpreted differently too, but it looks like the community doesn't feel very strongly about coming up with clearer tag guidance, whether it's because they dislike the tag as a whole, or strongly don't care about it.

#### The dispute

Given this response from the community, I eventually edited two posts (not any particular ones, just ones I've stumbled upon at some point) with the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq)tag that I believe were inappropriately tagged:

- [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/5740428)
- [Copy constructor and = operator overload in C++: is a common function possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734628/5740428)

In both of these cases, user @sbi (who started the C++ FAQ project) has added the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) tag single-handedly, and without asking the community for guidance first (to my knowledge). In general, @sbi had a habit of single-handedly applying this tag to [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) questions, especially ones they answer. The C++ FAQ tag has a strong connotation of inviting edits, beyond what is normally done on the website. Its excerpt states:

> Provides a collaborative, community-edited C++ FAQ

If it's not in the intent of the author to open the FAQ up to additional collaboration, and to emphasize community-edits, then adding this tag conflicts with the intent of the author.
Since the community didn't seem interested in discussing the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) usage, and since this edit looks like it's objectively against site policy, I have decided to roll it back. Note that the [helper center post on editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) states that one of the reasons to edit a question is:

> To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)

The edit changes the meaning from a personal Q&A into one which heavily encourages edits from the community.
Such a change in meaning can only be done by the author.
The help center also doesn't list any other valid reason that this edit could be justified with.
If I had seen this edit in review queue, I would have rejected it for conflicting with the intent of the author. I believe this is a reasonable standard for rollbacks.

Another user then decided to roll back my edits. They commented:

> Note that I will keep rolling back edits that remove this FAQ tag, @JanSchultke. As my answer states, these kinds of opinionated changes have to be discussed with the community, first. If that discussion concludes in a consensus that says the tags need to be removed, that's fine, but you can't just go ahead and change it of your own accord.

I'm not proud of having engaged in this edit war myself, but it is what it is. More discussion here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426723/5740428

#### Note on Q&A age

Note that both these edits are more than a decade old. Intuitively, any edit on a popular question which has not been rolled back for such a long period of time is "well-established" and shouldn't be rolled back without prior Meta discussion.<sup>(1)</sup>

However, I don't believe that this really matches how Stack Overflow operates. For example, there are countless questions about C++ with more than 100 score which have "C++" in the title, despite in-title tagging being advised against by the help center. For example, there is [What is the '-->' operator in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/). There are also countless old questions that could have improved tagging. For example, [Are the days of passing const std::string & as a parameter over?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10231349/) could need a [stdstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdstring) tag.

Overall, I don't believe that mere age somehow protects a question from edits, or that we should assume that a revision of a question shouldn't be touched just because the revision is old.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>I'm bringing up this argument of "old edits are well-established" because the argument of age has been used to argue against my edit. I personally don't believe in it.</sub>

#### The question

Now that we have this dispute, the question is whether the [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) should be applied to these two questions or not.

Comment: Good thing you posted this in Meta. You should have done so 15 rollbacks ago.

Comment: I have preventively locked both posts for one day to give some time to the interested parties to discuss, before any further edit can be made.

Comment: _"Intuitively, any edit which has not been rolled back for such a long period of time is "well-established" and shouldn't be rolled back without prior Meta discussion."_ That's simply not so.

Comment: "this edit looks like it's objectively against site policy" Can you please clarify why you think this is the case? This looks like the *potentially* strongest argument for your change, so it would be good to have it concretely spelled out.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I agree; I've quoted the help center on this one. To be fair, the help center doesn't provide very detailed and strict guidance on when to make edits, so it's not the strongest argument.

Comment: This probably boils down to "are these tags useful at all, or not". I do not think they are good tags, they seem like meta-tags to me. But obviously some disagree, and each "sub-community" has their own standards, for better or worse. Maybe this "war" can help clear up if the tags are good or not... or just kick the problem a couple of years down the road.

Comment: Please do not add any more comments about who started what. Remember that it takes at least **two** people to have an edit war, debating about who started it is pointless.

Answer (score 16):

The main reason you seem to feel that the addition of the tag is problematic is due to the following tag excerpt:

> Provides a collaborative, community-edited C++ FAQ

Specifically the points "collaborative" and "community-edited" are what you are concerned about. In my opinion these points are a problem yes but due to an entirely different reason. **All** posts on Stack Overflow are collaborative and community-edited with some limitations, we do have [Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) which allows easier editing by other users. In my opinion a tag **should not** be used for the purpose of indicating that one invites collaboration.

If we further look at the tag info the first paragraph states:

> Questions tagged [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) are meant to answer questions that are frequently asked in the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag on Stack Overflow.

Which doesn't state anything about "collaborative" or "community-edited", neither is it stated anywhere in the rest of the tag info, so that is most probably not the main consideration of the tag. Hence if anything should be edited, it should be the tag excerpt first and those words should be removed.

I won't discuss the utility of the tag or the need of it and leave it up to the C++ subject matter experts to discuss in your previous question. But in this case removing the tag assuming an arbitrary conflict with the authors intent does not seem correct to me.

Comment: I agree that there's a problem with inviting collaboration through a tag. If the excerpt was edited to simply state "Frequently asked C++ questions.", this edit war would still not be resolved though, since it's extremely subjective what constitutes a "frequently asked question". We don't have any objective standard. For example, there is [What is the '-->' operator in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028/) with over 10K upvotes, but I don't believe that this question is frequently asked nowadays, since `-->` is more of a cool trick than something you encounter in real code.

Comment: @JanSchultke I did mention that I'd leave discussing of the tags utility / purpose to C++ experts in your previous question :) Although yes, I do agree, I personally don't see much utility in that tags existence.

Comment: @JanSchultke: If it's *extremely subjective what constitutes a "frequently asked question"* then perhaps you should let the author's judgment stand unless it's egregiously and obviously wrong.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I've made the edit because of the connotation of inviting edits from the community, which is a signal of encouragement that only the author can send. No one should be able to put unintended words into the mouth of the author by adding this tag. At least I believe that the tag has that connotation, although it's becoming clear that not everyone thinks so, and the excerpt has multiple interpretations. I have not made the edit because I personally believe that the question is not frequently asked. That would indeed be subjective.