# Some clarification needed on the problematic and deprecated [history] tag

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I was just about to ask a question on SO that is technically very similar to the question [Why does C have these weird translation limits (section 2.2.4.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969672/why-does-c-have-these-weird-translation-limits-section-2-2-4-1), though perhaps slightly different in spirit.

When I searched for relevant tags to add, I started typing *history*, leading me to [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) and its related wiki page, warning me about the following:

> DO NOT use this tag for questions about the history of a programming concept or feature; those questions are off-topic.

After reading about the reasons behind its [deprecation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255424/how-should-the-history-tag-be-disambiguated), and a relevant question on [meta.programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic), I'm still at loss.

I feel that if [Why does C have these weird translation limits (section 2.2.4.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969672/why-does-c-have-these-weird-translation-limits-section-2-2-4-1) is on topic, then my question-to-be is on topic. However, just because a question has escaped the clutches of the diligent moderators doesn't necessarily mean it's on-topic, although it *was* recently posted, a fair bit after the ominous last edit to the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag.

My question is definitely not about *programming* history, so it should really not go to programmers. It is about a very specific tool and its implementation and usage.

It is however a *why* question, which should be off-topic on any site on the stack exchange network according to the boilerplate *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* written on every page in the help center. A literal interpretation of that sentence would exclude a lot of very good questions.

#### ... and now to my actual meta question

Is [Why does C have these weird translation limits (section 2.2.4.1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969672/why-does-c-have-these-weird-translation-limits-section-2-2-4-1) on topic considering present-day stackoverflow culture, and can I interpret its continued existence as a guideline to what type of questions I can ask?

Comment: I can't see anything problematic with that question you linked?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It goes against "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.". The comment "History of Programming is off-topic on Stack Overflow." in [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255425/5725780) caused the update to the `history` tag. The question is about the _reasons_ for the limits being as they are, for an old version of a programming standards, definitely not an actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Why does C have these weird translation limits (section 2.2.4.1)?
>   on topic considering present-day stackoverflow culture, and can I
>   interpret its continued existence as a guideline to what type of
>   questions I can ask?

It's a very specific (not too broad) question about language features in C when it comes to compilers. I don't see a problem with this question. In fact, it is well asked. Despite the list of examples the OP presents, the actual question is direct and specific, and got a direct and specific accepted answer.