# This tag is [history]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There is currently a [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag on Stack Overflow. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/history/info) for this tag says:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. This tag has become a catch-all tag for a number of history-related programming concepts. Please see the full tag wiki entry for usage.

If this tag isn't supposed to be used, why does it even exist? According to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255424/4284627), there are several other more specific tags that can be used instead for questions about a programming concept called "history":

> - [browser-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-history) for managing browser history in web applications and web browser extensions
> - [history.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history.js) for the JavaScript API to the HTML5 History APIs
> - [html5-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-history) for the HTML5 History API
> - [input-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input-history) for saving and recalling previous inputs in an entry box
> - [revision-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revision-history) for version control
>
> There may well be other meanings that I've missed.

<sub>(note by the way that this question isn't a duplicate since the other question doesn't ask to burninate the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag)</sub>

There are many good questions tagged [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) (by good, I mean in this case a few upvotes), but these questions can be retagged using one of the above tags (or possibly some other tag that isn't in that list).

This tag is also used for off-topic questions. Some of these questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41886029/4284627), are about the history of programming. Such questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow, as decided in [Are questions about programming history in scope for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow)  ([+16/-2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276367) answer saying off-topic and no real dissent).

But that's not the worst. There are several question which are only about history and have absolutely nothing to do with programming. Here are two examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/41917315/4284627 ([Screenshot for <10k users in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnZqP.png))
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/41696582/4284627 ([Screenshot for <10k users in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JChZL.png))

I think we can all agree, these questions don't belong on Stack Overflow.

Here are the [criteria to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/349538):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   I guess it usually describes the contents of the question, but it's certainly not unambiguous and most on-topic questions tagged [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) can use a more specific tag instead (and in the rare cases where the needed tag doesn't exist, it can always be created).
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   No. Some history questions might be asked on [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/), and questions about programming history are also, as I already mentioned, off-topic. There may be programming concepts called "history" (like browser history), but there are more specific tags for those.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?**

   In most cases, yes, but either posts that [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) adds any meaningful information to are off-topic or can use a more specific tag instead.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   No. The [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag can have at least 5 different on-topic meanings (see the list of tags above), and can also have off-topic meanings like programming history or just history that has nothing to do with programming.

So questions tagged [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) are either off-topic or can be retagged to use tags that are more specific. Also, since the tag wiki says explicitly "DO NOT USE THIS TAG", I don't see why it should be there at all.

Comment: This burninate request is not all it's quacked up to be...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255424/how-should-the-history-tag-be-disambiguated

Comment: Suggested title: This tag is [history]

Comment: Suggested title: burn the [history]

Comment: How about: [history] is history

Comment: the einstein question was just deleted, too bad...

Comment: It's nice that on the "programming
community" stackexchange you can discuss everything about history _except_ if it relates to programming (or computers in general, probably).

Comment: Could you please justify *why* history of programming is off-topic? “A moderator once said so” doesn't make it true. Topicality is determined by the community. The determination that history of programming is off-topic should be done in a meta discussion. As a point of comparison, most Stack Exchange sites do welcome questions about the history of their discipline.

Comment: Robert Harvey has kindly pointed out [a 2014 discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276366/are-questions-about-programming-history-in-scope-for-stack-overflow). With a [+16/-2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276367) answer and no real dissent, this can reasonably be taken to be a policy that history questions are off-topic.

Answer (score -13):

No, the tag should not be burninated. It needs to disappear, but not by burnination.

The [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag is widely used where some other tag would be more appropriate ([browser-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-history), etc.), and on questions that are off-topic (because they're about the history of programming).

We need to go through questions with this tag and, for each question, either:

- retag it to [browser-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/browser-history), etc. where applicable (don't forget to correct any other problem you see with the question while you're at it — other bad tags, uninformative title, spelling or formatting problems, etc.);
- close it (without removing the tag) if it's off-topic because it's about the history of programming (or otherwise in need of closing);
- just remove the tag (and fix any other problem) if it doesn't fit in any of the categories.

Once the off-topic questions have been closed and deleted, the tag will be removed automatically.

The tag fails criterion #3: does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? Yes, it does — it's either a signpost indicating that the question is off-topic, or a *partial* tag name that needs to be disambiguated. Burnination is for tags that don't convey any information at all. Historically, Stack Overflow was encumbered with a lot of bad tags inherited from the early, “wild West” days, but these days most of them have been cleaned up, so burnination is not that common. Disambiguation is far more common, and that can't be done automatically.

Comment: I think you've just described burnination process, even though you name it differently

Comment: @Vadim No: burnination means having Stack Exchange staff remove the tag without editing the questions.

Comment: @Gilles Vadim is right. You can review the burnination process [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7296893). There is little done by the Stack Exchange staff, it's mostly a user effort, with mods contributing now and then and mostly removing all closed questions in one batch. Step 4 (cleanup) involves retagging all questions that shouldn't be closed to appropriate tags (note that there have been exceptions, like burnination of the internet tag).