# What should we do with [python2to3] and [python-2to3]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43568009/2441442) which was tagged with those two tags:

- [python2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2to3) (For differences between python 2 and 3)
- [python-2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2to3) (a Tool)

Are both tags on topic?
Both tags are very ambiguous to each other.

So what should we do?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I don't see any reason why there needs to be a [python2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2to3) tag for differences between the two languages. The [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tags sufficiently cover those questions, so I'd recommend burninating the [python2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python2to3) tag (it's just 10 questions anyway).

The [python-2to3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2to3) tag (about the tool) seems valid and is used correctly on quite a few of the questions that have that tag (there are a lot of exceptions though where the tag should be removed). Overall, I'd still say that this one can stay as it is.

We should probably also add a disclaimer to the tag description along the lines of:

> Don't use this tag to ask about differences between Python 2 and
>   Python 3. Use the [python-2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) and [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) tags for that.

Comment: I doubt that many people will read that disclaimer. There are at the moment I'm writing this 1348 questions tagged [[history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history)] although the tag wiki says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" ([see also my burninate request for \[history\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343030/4284627)). If you think [python2to3] should be burninated, you can do that yourself: just edit it out of those 10 questions and it will be burninated automatically after a few hours if no questions are tagged with it.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Disclaimers never work 100% of the time but I'm pretty sure that they reduce the number of wrongly tagged questions (There are people who read the tag description before adding it after all). They are also useful for editors who might be unsure whether or not a particular tag should be removed or not. As for burinating the tag: I know that I could just go ahead and do it myself but that would kind of defeat the point of this question / discussion. I'd rather wait for some input from the community first.

Comment: Since you already have had 15 upvotes, I have burninated `python2to3`. The other tag still needs some observation.

Comment: It seems many questions that use [tag:python2to3] to ask about the library contain the expression "2to3". So [this search for all tagged questions not containing "2to3"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-2to3%5D+-2to3) might be a start to find out which questions need a tag cleanup.

Comment: [This improved query additionally filtering the results so it only displays questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-2to3%5D+-2to3+is%3Aquestion) might help even more.

Comment: I don't see why [tag:python-2to3] can't be used for question about differences in the context of migration. The pair of tags is more fit if the code needs to be made compatible with both versions at the same time.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Disappointed. The history tag did not have the history questions I expected.

Comment: @Keiwan I've proposed an edit to add your disclaimer (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15987229) (just copied the wording). I hope you are okay with this.

Comment: @TuringTux Thanks. I'd approve it if I had enough (5k) rep.